# Are tags of the handlers ignored?

Tags: ansible

We use handlers to restart services, when the service-configuration files change. Duh...

However, *sometimes* such immediate restarts are undesired -- so we tagged all such handlers with the same tag (`restart`) hoping, that invoking `ansible-playbook` with `--skip-tags=restart` will avoid the restart.

But it didn't -- the handlers still "fired"... I'm wondering, if that's a bug or a deliberate design-decision -- and what's it based on, if so...

Comment: One may also have a look into [Controlling when handlers run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run).